# PowerBI | How to dynamically select imported files in a Dashboard (Connectiontype: Folder)

Tags: dynamic, import, powerbi, parameter-passing, powerquery

I'm importing multiple log files from a folder. Is there a possibility on providing a slicer or something else on a dashboard for users to select which logs they want to check.

Would be cool if they could filter by name and date, which logs they want to check without importing data for every single file.

I'm also not yet sure on how to display the error messages per log-file ideally because we have for each day:

- Batch1
- Batch2
- Batch3
- Batch1_restart
- Batch1_restart
- Batch2_restart

There can be an random number of restarts of those three batches, if an error occurs. So it should also be possible to show the latest logs of those batches by default. But I guess those are things I can figure out, when I have an idea on how to filter the import according to user input.

Thank you for the assistance in advance!